# How do you set up a domain alias while running dnsmasq?

Tags: osx-lion, hosts, dnsmasq

I know the following rules in my dnsmasq.conf file will redirect all requests with a ".dev" top level domain back to my local machine.

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

The problem I am having is that I want to set up an alias such that "myserver" gets directed to a real address out on the net "myserver.example.com".

Before installing dnsmasq, I used an entry in my hosts file to accomplish the task, something like...

```
555.555.555.555   myserver
```

This allowed me to simply type something like:

```
ssh myserver
```

to connect to my remote server.

**The problem, this no longer works since I installed dnsmasq.**

I have tried to configure dnsmasq to direct these requests to the proper server but so far I have had no luck. A few things I have tried unsuccessfully include...

1) using the "local" configuration directive in the following manner:

```
local=/myserver/
```

It was my understanding that this would force dnsmasq to use the hosts file for looking up the alias, it did not.

2) I tried defining an address entry in the configuration:

```
address=/myserver/555.555.555.555
```

Maybe it is a syntax issue, but this did not work either.

3) I tried adjusting the hosts file on the computer to alias the full host name like so...

```
myserver.example.com  myserver
```

This like the above, did not work either.

Anyone have any suggestions on what to try next?

Thanks in advance.